# What kind of contour can be used for evaluating this integral?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I have the following integral:

$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^\infty\frac{\arctan(\eta_2+x)}{(x+\eta_1)^2+\eta_3^2}\ d x$

where $\eta_1$, $\eta_2$ and $\eta_3$ are real numbers. If the integrand were even it could be evaluated through the residue theorem because limits of the integral could be changed to form $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and a semicircular contour in the upper (or lower) half plane could be used. But in this case I can't figure out how to close the region to use the residue theorem. I can't also find another method to evaluate the integral.

Can someone please offer a solution to the conclusion of this problem?

Comment: i would start by taking a deruivative w.r.t $\eta_2$

Comment: ....and the final integral will look distusting, regardless what you are doing.

Comment: What are the signs of $\eta_i$'s? We should know their signs if we want to do contour integration (otherwise, we should do case work, which is very annoying)

Comment: Here $η_1$ is negative and $η_3$ is positive. $η_2$ could be either positive or negative. So we should do case work for only η2.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x+1)}{x^2+1}\,dx $$ does not have a nice closed form, so to crack the general integral with three parameters is quite hopeless, IMHO. What is the purpose of the computation of such integral?

Comment: This integral represents displacement in an elastic medium. It was obtained via the Poisson's formula for the elastic half-space. If we change the variable the integral turns to $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\eta_3} \int\limits_{\eta_1/\eta_3}^\infty \frac{\arctan(\eta_3 x+\eta_2-\eta_1)}{x^2+1}\ d x$$ but it is still hopeless.